# Can't copy file content in python on windows

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to copy file content from one file to another:

```
srcp = './output/name.jar'
dstp = './output/name'
os.remove(dstp)
src = open(srcp, 'r')
dst = open(dstp, 'w+b')
shutil.copyfileobj(src, dst)

src.close()
dst.close()

print os.path.getsize(srcp)
print os.path.getsize(dstp)
```

result is:

```
213815
3896
```

When I specify the length argument in `shutil.copyfileobj` copid size changes, but also wrong, cut constant for each `length`.

`shutil.copyfile` works fine, but I need to copy content because of my code copies another information before file content. In this test case I just trying to copy.

System: win 7 x32

Comment: Why do you use binary mode to write, but "text mode" to read?

Comment: @Gandaro Why do you use comment mode to answer? So I got your score points now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have disagreeing file modes.

```
src = open(srcp, 'r')
dst = open(dstp, 'w+b')
```

You should use `'rb'` for reading. Otherwise, line breaks are treated wrong, and 0x1A is recognized as EOF.